# Preloading a .css file with NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

We are using NextJS and Material-UI for our site, and upon loading the pages, it gives a FOUC. I've narrowed the problem down to the fact that the JS loads faster than the .css file, so I was wondering if there was a way to preload the .css file? All of our pages use the same .css file which is located under `/pages/styles.css`

Here is `/pages/_app.js` if that's any help:

```
// pages/_app.js
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/client'
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import styles from './styles.css'

import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Head from 'next/head'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#2196f3", // blue
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#d3d3d3", // gray
    },
  },
});

export default function _App ({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Provider options={{ clientMaxAge: 0, keepAlive: 0 }} session={pageProps.session}>
        <Layout>  
          {/* Head */}
          <Head>
            <title>Kevin Support</title>
            <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.png"/>
          </Head>

          {/* Page */}
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </Provider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Have you tried importing the styles directly from the node_modules? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#import-styles-from-node_modules

Comment: The styles are coming from a file I have called styles.css, not node_modules

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66089559/1870780 help answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps styles weren't applied on the server-side. Try to add `_document.js` from Material-UI's Next.js [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js). Adjust it to your needs.

```
// pages/_document.js
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from '../src/theme';

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

// `getInitialProps` belongs to `_document` (instead of `_app`),
// it's compatible with server-side generation (SSG).
MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles), sheets.getStyleElement()],
  };
};
```

Also, you can try to remove server-side injected CSS in the `_app.js` like so (see [example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_app.js)):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentElement.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `display: none;` on the body element until the style sheet has loaded then `display: block;`

Answer (score -1):

Load the CSS file with the `<link>` element inside the head. The parsing process of the browser will then make sure that the CSS file is loaded before the site content is shown.

In your current approach you load the CSS is loaded with JavaScript, after the FCP has rendered the CSS will be parsed.

You have 2 options to fix this:

1. You link the CSS file as mentioned above with a `<link>` element.
2. You get the text content of the CSS file and set it as the `innerHTML` of a `<style>` element.

Comment: How exactly would I link the .css file with a ```<link>``` element? I tried 
```<link rel="stylesheet" href="/pages/styles.css"/>```   and it still flashes upon page load

Comment: You would not use a link tag directly using nextjs as nextjs is highly dynamic and would create them for you

Answer (score -1):

I faced this same issue.
what I did was to make this work was to add this script inside _document.tsx

```js
     <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `
              if(document) {
            document.querySelectorAll("link[rel='preload'][as='style']").forEach(link => link.rel = "stylesheet")}
            `
            }}
          />
```