# How to read nextjs error messages or locate error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have error messages in a next.js react project and I cant understand what they are saying at all. I realise this question is very general but I really have no idea how to proceed and I don't know where else to look. There are no instances of the text 'SvgLogo' anywhere in my project (outside of the the .next folder where there are some) but I think it is safe to assume the error is in my code not in the framework. So how can I find it?

For example

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `Styled(SvgLogo)`.
SvgLogo
O@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1616098032894:71023:19542`
...
```

and

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "sc-irOQnY csyezN" Client: "sc-iBPRYJ iOFUQl"
svg
SvgLogo
O@http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/index.js?ts=1616098032894:71023:19542
...
```

Comment: Are you using any React components library by any chance?

Comment: Yes, Material-Ui

Comment: For the second issue this might help: [MaterialUI makeStyles undoes custom css upon refresh in NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66089559/1870780).