# I'm using NextJs With Material Ui but some styles applied after 2 refresh in my page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, styles, server-side-rendering

Hello Guys I'm using material ui with nextjs and my problem is that some styles are applied after 2 refresh in my page

the images show the differences before and after refreshing page

[before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzFEd.jpg)

[after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJONv.jpg)

the code i'm using :

```
<Hidden xsDown>
        <Box width="100%"  >
        <Container >
        <Grid xs={12} md={10} lg={11} className="dev-slider" >
          {/* <CarouselBox event={props.myevent} /> */}
          <Slider/>
        </Grid>
        </Container>
        </Box>
      </Hidden>

      {/* Sect Two */}
      <div className="dev-divide-top">
        <Box width="85%" alignItems="flex-end">
          <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="space-between">
              <Grid item={true} xs={12} md={4} lg={3} direction="column">
                <Hidden xsDown>
                  <NewestSidebar />
    
                  <PupTitles />
                  <SidebarNewTech />
                </Hidden>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item={true} xs={12} md={8} lg={9} direction="column">
                <Hidden xsDown>
                  <ShowPost />
                </Hidden>
                <Hidden xsDown>
                  <CardPosts event={props.myevent} />
                </Hidden>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Container>
        </Box>
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you setup Material-UI stylesheets in your custom `_document` to support SSR, as described in [MaterialUI makeStyles undoes custom css upon refresh in NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66089559/1870780)?